# Ubuntu won't boot from SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, ssd

Previously I've had windows installed to a SSD in my laptop and ubuntu installed to HDD on it. Recently I've changed that HDD to SSD and installed ubuntu there as usual, but for some reason it won't boot now. GRUB says `alloc magic is broken`. Boot repair didn't help. Here's [boot repair's report](http://paste2.org/0BfWG5aK) btw.

The strange thing I've noticed is that previously GRUB was loading from the device where ubuntu was installed (the HDD), but now BIOS says ubuntu loader is located on the same device, where windows. Does it tell about something?
How can I fix this stuff and make dual boot ubuntu work from SSD?

Comment: Did you try http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001993 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair ?

Comment: No. chroot didn't help. It just made windows boot loader absent from grub but grub still won't work. About the boot-repair, I've written in my post that it didn't help from the very beginning